# Avada Wordpress Theme, cannot resize logo ( using cafe demo content )

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, size

I'm using the Avada Wordpress theme and have installed the Cafe Site Demo Content.  I went into Appearance > Theme Options > Logo and uploaded my image logo file but it seems to lock it to a tiny size in that top left menu corner. I remade the logo image at double the size and re uploaded it and it still is the same small size on the website, I cannot find an option to allow me to increase the logo size.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try https://theme-fusion.com/support/

Comment: Check in the CSS there may be a rule to have the logo at a specific size - do you have a link to the project?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.  http://digital.coffee is the url at the moment.   my custom logo is the one in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Your header container has a fixed height of 70px in your css. 
You need to change into a new height of 100px for instance and delete the max-width of img.

```
.header_mid {
height: 100px;
}

img{
/* max-width: 100%; */
}
```

This should work!